# How to skip nodes in an XMLDocument in C#

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

Say I have an XML document like this

```
<xml>
     <food>
            <banana>this is a banana</banana>
            <apple>this is an apple</apple>
            <grape>this is a grape</grape>
     </food>
     <food>
            <cake>this is cake</cake>
            <soda>this is soda</soda>
            <cookie>this is a cookie</cookie>
     </food>
</xml>
```

How would I skip to the second node of `<food>` to get the food from in there using an XMLDocument in C#? Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: What did you tried? There are several ways to read a xml, which did you use?

Comment: ` Doc = new XmlDocument();
  Doc.Load(this.xml);`

Answer (score 1):

```
XmlDocument xdcDocument = new XmlDocument();

xdcDocument.LoadXml(<xml string>);

XmlElement xelRoot = xdcDocument.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList xnlNodes = xelRoot.SelectNodes("/food");

bool first = true;
foreach(XmlNode xndNode in xnlNodes)
{
    if (first) {
        first = false;
        continue;
    }
    // process the second node here
}
```

Comment: I would use: `XmlNode xndNode = xnlNodes.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: @Joroen van Langen - Yes, I think your way is more elegant than what I wrote, thanks for the comment.

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Getting error as, XmlNodeList doesn't have definition for Skip() method.

Comment: @Abhinandan It's from the Enumeral extention methods. include `using System.Linq`  at the usings.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Enumerable.Skip` (from the idea of @JeroenvanLangen in comments) but it needs a little trick:

```
XmlNodeList xnlNodes = Doc.SelectNodes("/food");
foreach(XmlNode node in xnlNodes.Cast<XmlNode>().Skip(1))
{
    //do sth
}
```

The cast trick is needed because XmlNodeList implements the interface `IEnumerable` but is not a `IEnumerable<XmlNode>`.